# What is the difference between these two functions in php?

Tags: php, function

These function statements are confusing me.

I'm new to php, help me to understand these functions:

```
function addFive($num)
{
$num += 5;
}

function addSix(&$num)
{
$num += 6;
}
$orignum = 10;
addFive( $orignum );
echo "Original Value is $orignum<br />";
addSix( $orignum );
echo "Original Value is $orignum<br />";
```

first echo outputs **10**
Second echo outputs **16**

What is the difference between these 2 functions?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of call:

1) Call by value: `addFive($num)`

2) Call by reference:  `addSix(&$num)`

In first case, you are just passing value of the variable.

Hence, only value gets modified keeping original variable untouched.

In second case, you are passing reference to the variable, hence the original value gets modified.

Comment: @Mani_k, if my answer works for you, please accept it as solution or choose any other answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The first function passes the argument **by value** - in other words, it's copied into the function, and any change you perform on it will be on the local copy.

The second function passes the argument **by reference** (note the `&` before it in the function's signature). This means the variable itself is passed, and any modification you perform on it will survive beyond the function's scope.

Comment: Sorry for this unuseful comment, but are you a professor at stanford or what ? you teach like a Gem !

Answer (score 1):

& is used to pass address of an variable in second function declaration "addSix(&$num) {}"

In second function while calling addSix( $orignum ); updation of value is done on address of "$orignum"

whereas in first function updation is done on "$num"

Answer (score 0):

First function add 5 to your number and second adds 6 to your number
`$num+=6` means `$num= $num+6`
And first function works on `Call by value` and second function works on `Call by reference`

Comment: if the first function add to my number means the ans is **15** know how come it is **10**

Comment: Because first function works on `Call by value` so your original value doesnt change

Comment: If you again call `addSix( $orignum );` it will return 22